# Django HttpResponseNotFound Not Displaying Correctly in View

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a Django project where I have a view called 'chapterPage' that is supposed to display a specific chapter. If the chapter with the given primary key (pk) doesn't exist, I want to return an HttpResponseNotFound response. However, I am encountering an issue where the "Chapter not found" is not being displayed when the chapter is not found.

Code snippets:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from .models import Chapter

def chapterPage(request, pk):
    try:
        chapter = Chapter.objects.get(id=pk)
    except Chapter.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Chapter not found")
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("chapter/<str:pk>/", views.chapterPage, name="chapter"),
]
```

The chapter link on the other webpage:

```
 <div> 
       <a href="{% url 'chapter' chapter.pk %}">{{chapter.number}}</a>

 </div>
```

I made sure that the chapter exists in the database with the intended pk. Also, when I'm trying to search for a chapter using the URL 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/chapter/5933/' the terminal returns 'Not Found: /chapter/5933/m' or 'Not Found: /chapter/5933/n', basically an intended URL with a random character afterward.

I am expecting to get HttpResponseNotFound("Chapter not found") if the chapter is not found.

P.S. I have just started learning so any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because the pk parameter in the url is treated as str type.

Try this in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("chapter/<int:pk>/", views.chapterPage, name="chapter"),
]
```

And I recommend using get_object_or_404() ([Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404))

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def chapterPage(request, pk):
    chapter = get_object_or_404(Chapter, id=pk)
```

Comment: I tried changing str to int but the issue still persists, I also have another view that uses str but still passes int as pk and it works just fine.

Comment: @yahordauksha Weird. Have you tried print(pk) and print(type(pk)) inside this method?

Comment: Yep, I just tried it, I get an expected pk with print(pk) and int with (print(type(pk)) (I changed str to int as you advised).